# String to Decimal with 2 decimal places always

Tags: c#, decimal

I have a string that is to be converted to decimal. The string could be entered with no decimal places e.g. "123" or 2 decimal places, e.g. "123.45" or somewhat awkwardly, 1 decimal place "123.3". I want the number displayed (the Property `invoice.Amount` which is type `decimal`) with 2 decimal places. The code below does that. I think it could be written better though. How?

```
decimal newDecimal;
bool isDecimal = Decimal.TryParse(InvoiceDialog.InvoiceAmount, out newDecimal);
string twoDecimalPlaces = newDecimal.ToString("########.00");
invoice.Amount = Convert.ToDecimal(twoDecimalPlaces);
```

In part, I don't understand, for the string formatting "########.00", what # does and what 0 does. E.g. how would it be different if it were "########.##"?

Comment: Everything mentioned in the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings

Comment: Regarding how you could write it better (although *better* in this case is very subjective), you could use `"N2"` for the format string instead of `"#######.00"`, which is a standard numeric format string instead of a custom one and supports locale-specific separators etc, as detailed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings)

Comment: Also you could just do `#.00` all those extra number signs in the format will make no difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`#` is an *optional* digit when `0` is a *mandatory* digit

For instance

```
 decimal d = 12.3M;

 // d with exactly 2 digits after decimal point
 Console.WriteLine(d.ToString("########.00"));
 // d with at most 2 digits after decimal point 
 Console.WriteLine(d.ToString("########.##"));
```

Outcome:

```
12.30   // exactly 2 digits after decimal point: fractional part padded by 0
12.3    // at most 2 digits after decimal point: one digit - 3 - is enough
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically, # means optional, where as 0 is mandatory.
As for better explanation, if you put # then if number is available to fullfil the placeholder it'll be added if not it'll be ignored.

Putting 0 however is different as it'll always put a value in for you.

You can combine the two together.

`String.Format("{0:0.##}", 222.222222);` // 222.22

`String.Format("{0:0.##}", 222.2);` // 222.2

`String.Format("{0:0.0#}", 222.2)`          // 222.2

Answer (score 1):

The "#" is optional while the "0" will show either the number or 0.

For example,

```
var x = 5.67;
x.ToString("##.###"); // 5.67
x.ToString("00.000"); // 05.670
x.ToString("##.##0"); // 5.670
```

If you just care about how many decimal places you have, I would recommend using

```
x.ToString("f2"); // 5.67
```

to get 2 decimal spots.

More information can be found at http://www.independent-software.com/net-string-formatting-in-csharp-cheat-sheet.html/.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to convert the `decimal` to `string` to do the formatting for 2 decimal places. You can use the `decimal.Round` method directly. You can read about it [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9s0xa85y.aspx).

So your code can be converted to

```
    decimal newDecimal;
    Decimal.TryParse(s, out newDecimal);

    newDecimal = decimal.Round(newDecimal, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
```

The above code also be simplified with C# 7.0 declaration expression as

```
    Decimal.TryParse(s, out decimal newDecimal);

    newDecimal = decimal.Round(newDecimal, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
```

Now newDecimal will have have a value with 2 precision.

You can check [this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/lDpQh0) live fiddle.

Comment: I think in this line `Decimal.TryParse(s, out decimal newDecimal);` the "decimal" after `out` causes a compile error. Also, it doesn't seem to work if you enter just "123".

Comment: Check this link about declaration expression for our variable —- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7.